# How to Integrate non supported fonts in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating a English to Mangolean Dictionary app; So i need to display mangolean word corresponding to my english word; i read from a blog that wp7 only supports limited language set. So how can i over come my issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: As the answers show this is possible but be aware of the licensing issues if distributing fonts yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the supported Fonts you can add your on fonts to you project. For example create a folder named Fonts in you project and add you *.TTF files(Font Files). By referring this font files you can resolve your issues.

Answer (score 4):

There's a tutorial on embedding fonts in Silverlight here: http://paulyanez.com/interactive/index.php/2009/12/embedding-fonts-in-silverlight/ The implementation for Windows Phone is exactly the same. The tutorial uses Expression Blend (which is part of the developer tools download and also free for Windows Phone), which is the simplest, quickest, and easiest way to embed fonts for Silverlight.