# Digital Clock or Timer in Window Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

[image]I want to display a digital timer in my WP7 application.

Actually i am working on a application for an event.

What i wan t to display is, that it diplay the application will begin in following by days, hours, minutes and seconds    and the time should decrease continously.

The Picture given above will give you an idea about what i want exactly.

What i need to do for it.
Any API or inbuilt control available which help me with this, or i need to work on it.

If nothing inbuilt is available than also your suggestions are gladly accepted.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: How far have you got already? What have you tried?

Comment: What i have done till now is, i have places text blocks and i am updating them using timers.

Comment: Try this... http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Silverlight-e28093-Create-a-binary-clock.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock should be easy, its just some text.  The biggest issue will be getting the right font into a project as WP7 doesn't have a digital font built in.  You can import external fonts into your project:
[How to Integrate non supported fonts in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551889/how-to-integrate-non-supported-fonts-in-wp7)

As other posters have said all you need to update the display, is have a timer raising a event once a second (or perhaps background worker thread in a sleep loop, as you should be able to get a little more control)

Answer (score 0):

The Display work shouldn't be a challenge after all, it's all just Xaml, designing it in blend should take you no time.

As for getting the date and time, the system wide "DateTime" classes are available just like they are in regular .net, and the 'now' & 'UtcNow' static properties will give you the exact time at that moment.

Getting at the .net stopwatch classes however is a little more tricky.

They are no longer in the system namespace, so instead have been moved to the phone specific namespace.

In your project, add a reference to Microsoft.Phone.dll and then you should have the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class available to you to use in your code, which works in the same way as it's counterpart in the desktop world.

Answer (score 0):

I have used This code

**XAML**

```
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtClockDays" Text="66:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="fonts/digital-7.ttf#Digital-7" FontSize="32"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtClockHours" Text="06:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="fonts/digital-7.ttf#Digital-7" FontSize="32"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtClockMinutes" Text="30:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="fonts/digital-7.ttf#Digital-7" FontSize="32"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtClockSeconds" Text="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="fonts/digital-7.ttf#Digital-7" FontSize="32"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock x:Name="txtDays" Text="Days" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtHours" Text="Hourss" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtMinutes" Text="Minutes" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtSeconds" Text="Secondss" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
```

**Code**

```
int diffDays, diffHours, diffMinutes, diffSeconds;
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        public HomeScreen()
        {
            //string mDate, mHours, mMinutes, mSeconds;
            InitializeComponent();
            dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
            dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);

            DateTime d1= DateTime.Now;
            DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 15, 10, 45, 00);
            TimeSpan span = d2.Subtract(d1);
            diffSeconds = span.Seconds;
            diffMinutes = span.Minutes;
            diffHours = span.Hours;
            diffDays = span.Days;

            txtClockDays.Text = diffDays.ToString();
            txtClockHours.Text = diffHours.ToString();
            txtClockMinutes.Text = diffMinutes.ToString();
            txtClockSeconds.Text = diffSeconds.ToString();

            dt.Start();
        }

        void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (diffSeconds <= 0)
            {
                diffSeconds = 59;
                if (diffMinutes <= 0)
                {
                    diffMinutes = 59;
                    if (diffHours <= 0)
                    {
                        diffHours = 59;
                        if (diffDays <= 0)
                        {
                            diffDays = 0;
                            diffHours = 0;
                            diffMinutes = 0;
                            diffSeconds = 0;
                            dt.Stop();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            diffDays = diffDays - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        diffHours = diffHours - 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    diffMinutes = diffMinutes - 1;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                diffSeconds = diffSeconds - 1;
            }


            //Dispalying the timer
            if (diffSeconds < 10)
            {
                txtClockSeconds.Text = "0" + diffSeconds.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtClockSeconds.Text = diffSeconds.ToString();
            }


            if (diffMinutes < 10)
            {
                txtClockMinutes.Text = "0" + diffMinutes.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtClockMinutes.Text = diffMinutes.ToString();
            }

            if (diffHours < 10)
            {
                txtClockHours.Text = "0" + diffHours.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtClockHours.Text = diffHours.ToString();
            }

            if (diffDays < 10)
            {
                txtClockDays.Text = "0" + diffDays.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtClockDays.Text = diffDays.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void btnRacenevents_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPivot.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

for the font i used in this code use this link:
http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/